# AddEventListener for multiple elements doesn't work with "focus" event

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm guessing I have a basic error in thinking but I just can't get around it.

I have a couple of text fields which I want to add an EventListener to. 
I put them all in one class and added the EventListener to this class.
Everyhing works perfect when event of choice is "click". But when I change it to "focus" nothing happens. Why is that?

this works:

```
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('click', emptyField, false);
```

this doesn not:

```
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('focus', emptyField, false);
```

text fields:

```js
function emptyField(e){
    var clicked = e.target;
 if (clicked.value == clicked.name)  {
  clicked.value='';
  
  if (clicked.id=='password') {
   clicked.type='password';
  }
 } 
}
```

```html
<class id="parent">
 <input type="text" name="USERNAME" id="username" value="USERNAME"><br>
 <input type="text" name="PASSWORD" id="password" value="PASSWORD" ><br>
</class>
```

Comment: Those two are the same... I think you meant `querySelector` or something? A querselector returns a NodeList, which you can't use to attach events, you will have to loop through it.

Comment: Using real examples would help us understand better. You said text fields but these examples don't show that. Please isolate your specific problem as much as you can so we can recreate it.

Comment: I want the function to react to the "focus" event, not "click". but it doens't work.

Comment: Your focus event is attached to the surrounding div. Set the events to the actual text fields. `document.getElementById('password')`

Comment: Yes I did that before and worked perfectly.. but in case I want to add more text fields I'd have to do that over and over again.. there most be a shorter way?

Comment: and how come it workes with "click" but not with "focus"?

Comment: Some browsers support `focusin` which bubbles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use `querySelectorAll()` that will return all the `input`s :

```
var fields = document.querySelectorAll('#parent input');
```

And use loop to attach `focus` event to every field :

```
for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].addEventListener('focus', emptyField, false);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The `click` event bubbles up to ancestor elements.

The `focus` event does not, and it is the `<input>` that is being focussed, not the outer element.

Comment: I didn't know that, thank you. So there's no way around adding every single textfield?

Comment: @BenQCat If you want to handle the `focus` even specifically, not really - you'll need to bind to it on each element that you want to receive the event on, though you can do so in the manner presented in [Zakaria's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33481053/791010) to save having to address every element individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to attach an event to several elements without an explicit loop, you can use a helper function:

```
    function attachEvents(elementList, eventName, handlerFunction) {
            if(typeof elementList == "string")
                    elementList = document.querySelectorAll(elementList);
            for(var i = 0; i < elementList.length; i++)
                    elementList[i].addEventListener(eventName, handlerFunction);
    }
```

You call it like this:

```
    attachEvents("#area button", "click", function(event) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
```

Or like this:

```
    attachEvents(document.getElementById("area").getElementsByTagName("button"), "click", function(event) {
            this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    });
```

You don't always want `document.querySelectorAll` - doing it yourself means you also do things like `some_element.querySelectorAll` which is really nice when working with things that aren't yet part of the document, or have no unique selector.

But regardless, putting the loop in a helper function gives you that jquery-esque one-liner without a huge library, it is just a few lines of simple code.