# addEventListener with multiple elements

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I started working with [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).
I have two **buttons**, and want change **backgroundColor** when click on any of these buttons.
But my code doesn't work.
This is my code:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    func(this)
});

function func(element){
    element.style.backgroundColor="gray";
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Play With Me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Play With Me!</button>
</div>
```

is there any way that an `addEventListener` works with multiple elements?

Comment: I know that this is a little off topic, but are you limited to vanilla javascript? You should look into jQuery.

Comment: You could take advantage of event delegation, bind your handler to an ancestor of the buttons and refer to the event's target to get the actual button that was clicked. You can achieve this in a few lines of code, even without jQuery.

Comment: jQuery is such a waste, this is a three line problem! Just use a loop, and if you want to get really fancy, make a helper function for it (seriously, three lines).

Comment: I wrote a potential helper function you can use as an answer on the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36797917/1457000 i went with 6 lines instead of 3 for a bit more convenience but same simple idea.

Comment: thanks every body! all of your advices are useful!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way is to have as few event listeners as possible in your code. So instead of attaching an event listener to each and every button, you can attach 1 single event listener to the `area` div and make suitable changes based on `event.target` attribute.

Run the below working code snippet:

```js
document.getElementById('area').addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  func(event.target);
});

function func(element) {
  element.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Play With Me!</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Play With Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks dear Adarsh Konchady! it's the most useful solution

Answer (score 6):

You could do it like this or [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/580/)

```js
 var button = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
 for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
   button[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
     this.style.backgroundColor = "gray";
   });
 }
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn1">Play With Me!</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="btn2">Play With Me!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Reason is `document.getElementsByTagName` returns an array of elements. `addEventListener` is a method on an element, not an array. So you need to iterate through all of them and call `addEventListener` on each one.

Comment: Technically, `getElementsByTagName` returns a live list rather than an array... it doesn't make a difference here, but if you ever change elements inside the loop, the live list matters - items you remove from the document will also magically disappear from the array, as you loop it!

Comment: It also makes a difference if you try to use array methods like push or splice on it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background color</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Set background color</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
</script>
```